Wix v3 od VS project convert to Wix v4 problems
Hi i have old VS Wix v3 project InstallerWix.wixproj.
And I need to upgrade it to wersion 4
And then for wersion 5 Wix
My project looks like that(https://i.sstatic.net/yk62wbr0.png)
I tryed upgrade it using HeatWave(https://i.sstatic.net/9QpF6DIK.png) but i gat this errors (https://i.sstatic.net/2Ak6E0M6.png)
In the project file there are such references, how to replace them ?(https://i.sstatic.net/xD3svBiI.png) (https://i.sstatic.net/IYTY0RrW.png)
i will gratefull for help
Paul

Try replacing the $(ProjectDir)Components.xslt in your .wixproj to the actual filename on disk. Based on the images you attached (why not put the text in the question to make it more searchable?) I think the value would be InstallerWixComponents.xslt.
The root issue is that HeatWave is not evaluating the $(ProjectDir) variable and that is why it can't find the file. HeatWave could be updated to handle that case... but this is the first time I've seen anyone do this.

Thanks Rob now it works, I'm glad that You answer me. I seen Your videos, grat work ;)could You look at my second problem please:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002207/wix-how-to-replace-library-usage-installutillib-dll

If this was the answer to your question, you should mark it as "Answered" (so it falls off my list of unanswered questions).

Hey Rob I marked this answer as "Answered", but if You can, see to my other topic because I really need help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002207/wix-how-to-replace-library-usage-installutillib-dll

I saw that question but didn't immediately understand what you were asking. I don't spend a lot of time on StackOverflow. The bulk of my time is spent addressing customer problems.

however, if You could find some time to consider my problem I would appreciate it
