WIX how to replace library usage InstallUtilLib.dll?
I have some old code related to the library InstallUtilLib.dll,
below fragment of Product.wxs (please note customactions Uninstall Install Commit):
 <Binary Id="InstallUtil" SourceFile="Binary\InstallUtilLib.dll" />    
 <Binary Id="Spos8OnboardInstall" SourceFile="Binary\Spos8OnboardInstall" />
 <Binary Id="InstallBannerSposOnboard" SourceFile="Content\InstallBannerSposOnboard.bmp" />
 <Binary Id="UpFldrBtn" SourceFile="Content\UpFldrBtn.jpg" />
 <Binary Id="NewFldrBtn" SourceFile="Content\NewFldrBtn.jpg" />

 <CustomAction Id="Uninstall" BinaryKey="InstallUtil" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
 <CustomAction Id="Uninstall.SetProperty" Property="Uninstall" Value=' /installtype=notransaction
                                                                       /action=uninstall 
                                                                       /menu="[CREATE_MENU_ITEMS]" 
                                                                       /desktop="[CREATE_DESKTOP_ICON]" 
                                                                       /manufacturer="[Manufacturer]" 
                                                                       /productname="[ProductName]"
                                                                       "[#filSpos]"
                                                                       "[#filSposConfig]"' />
 <CustomAction Id="Install" BinaryKey="InstallUtil" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
 <CustomAction Id="Install.SetProperty" Property="Install"  Value='/installtype=notransaction 
                                                                   /action=install
                                                                   /MODE="INSTALL"
                                                                   /menu="[CREATE_MENU_ITEMS]"
                                                                   /desktop="[CREATE_DESKTOP_ICON]"
                                                                   /serial="[SERIAL]" 
                                                                   /vesselname="[VESSEL_NAME]"
                                                                   /companyname="[COMPANY_NAME]"
                                                                   /manufacturer="[Manufacturer]"
                                                                   /productname="[ProductName]"
                                                                   /title="[Title]"
                                                                   /MsiPath="[OriginalDatabase]|"
                                                                   /RWFolder="[RWFOLDER]|"
                                                                   "[#filSpos]"
                                                                   "[#filSposConfig]"' />
 <CustomAction Id="Commit" BinaryKey="InstallUtil" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="commit" Impersonate="no" />
 <CustomAction Id="Commit.SetProperty" Property="Commit" Value=' /installtype=notransaction 
                                                                 /action=commit 
                                                                 /menu="[CREATE_MENU_ITEMS]" 
                                                                 /desktop="[CREATE_DESKTOP_ICON]" 
                                                                 /manufacturer="[Manufacturer]" 
                                                                 /productname="[ProductName]" 
                                                                 "[#filSpos]"  
                                                                 "[#filSposConfig]"' />

and next it is used in install process (Uninstall, Commit, Instal) like below:
  <AdminExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="DIRCA_TARGETDIR" Sequence="750">TARGETDIR=""</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Uninstall.SetProperty" Sequence="1698">$cmpSpos=2</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Uninstall" Sequence="1699">$cmpSpos=2</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Commit.SetProperty" Sequence="5996">$cmpSpos&gt;2</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Commit" Sequence="5997">$cmpSpos&gt;2</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Install.SetProperty" Sequence="5998">$cmpSpos&gt;2</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Install" Sequence="5999">$cmpSpos&gt;2</Custom>   
  </AdminExecuteSequence>

Because during the instalation I get this message-box
Error 1001. InstallUtilLib.dll CorBindToRuntimeHost (hr=0x80070003). The system cannot find the path specified.
Firstly, I would like to know what this code does?
Probably I need to remove this binary reference and to replace this old solution with another native Wix solution.
Maybe you know:

what to do to prevent the error message from appearing?
what this old code does and how it can be replaced with a new solution?

I have no idea how to replace it with another solution.
